# копирование и архивирование файлов по дате в BASH

Tags: bash

Есть папка `directory`, в которой лежат файлы:

- `file1.ogg` *(дата создания 01.08)*;
- `randomfile2.ogg` *(дата создания 10.08)*;
- `filename3.ogg` *(дата создания 15.08)*.

Хочу написать скрипт, который по команде:

`sh tar_by_date.sh directory/ '08.08' '28.08'`   *# (путь, начальная дата, конечная дата)*

Создаёт архив `directory.tar.gz` из указанной папки с файлами, у которых дата создания входит в указанный промежуток

Какими командами и как правильно пользоваться?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tar cfz archive.tar.gz `find -type f -newermt 2021-05-30 -not -newermt 2021-06-15`
```

Команда создаст архив из файлов, которые модифицированы после 2021-05-30, но не позже чем 2021-06-15.

Команда `find` поддерживает несколько видов [предикатов "новее чем"](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Comparing-Timestamps.html#Comparing-Timestamps). Кроме того есть возможность задать относительный возраст ["старше, чем несколько дней назад"](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html#Age-Ranges)

Варианты форматов даты описаны в [документации `date`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats).